# SEO optimization and DNS

Tags: seo

We are creating a site where we want to SEO optimize the domain name. So when people go to tutorsNewYork.com they should see all New York related content on our site. If they go to tutorBoston.com, they should see all Boston related content. How can we accomplish this using DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With DNS you can only specify the Server which will process your request. For that reason it's not the thing you're looking for.

You can point all your domains to the same server (and even directory) and then with you server side application (e.g. PHP) you can deside which content to be shown.

```
<?php
  switch($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
    case "tutorsNewYork.com":
    case "www.tutorsNewYork.com":
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `tutors` WHERE `city` = 'NY';";
    break;
   case "tutorsNewYork.com":
   case "www.tutorsBoston.com":
     $query = "SELECT * FROM `tutors` WHERE `city` = 'Boston';";
   break;
 }
 ?>
```